# How do you sort GitHub search results from search bar?

Tags: github

There are some search syntax examples on [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/). If you scroll to the button the documentation mentions that you can sort the results in ascending or descending or by date. This is true, but you have to click on a little dropdown to make it happen, please see attaching image.
[image]
I'm wondering is it possible to use some kind of search syntax to sort the results without having to click on the dropdown?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `sort` keyword in the search box to sort results.

For example, if you want to sort Issues that you have commented on by the number of comments, you would use `is:issue commenter:[your GitHub handle] sort:comments`. The dropdown on the results page won't match the sort when you specify one but the results are sorted.

To sort in a particular order, you can place `-desc` or `-asc` for descending or ascending order respectively. To extend the previous example, it would be `is:issue commenter:[your GitHub handle] sort:comments-asc` to sort from least to most number of comments on Issues where you commented.

[image: Sorting by number of comments from least to most]

---

Read the official GitHub documentation for more details:
[Sorting search results](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/sorting-search-results)